# Is there a way to override the AtomFeedBuilder updated_at value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, actionviewhelper

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AtomFeedHelper/AtomFeedBuilder.html), an entry's `updated` value `Defaults to the updated_at attribute on the record if one such exists.` I'm trying to override the `updated` value, but instead I'm getting two `updated` fields in my RSS feed.

If I set a different updated value with this (truncated) example...

```
feed.entry(item) do |entry|
  entry.updated(item.not_the_updated_at_value.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
end
```

...Then I end up with two `updated` fields in my RSS feed:

```
<entry>
    <id>1</id>
    <published>2010-03-30T13:11:07-07:00</published>
    <updated>2010-03-30T13:11:07-07:00</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.com/1"/>
    <title>Title</title>
    <content type="html">Content</content>
    <url>http://example.com/1/</url>
    <updated>2012-07-10T11:05:32Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Author</name>
    </author>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the published and updated options into entry.

```
feed.entry(item, :published => item.published_at, 
                   :updated => item.published_at) do |entry|
  entry.content item.body, :type => 'html'
end
```